# How do I get information about function calls from a Lua script?

Tags: reflection, lua, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a script written in Lua 5.1 that imports third-party module and calls some functions from it. I would like to get a list of function calls from a module with their arguments (when they are known before execution).

So, I need to write another script which takes the source code of my first script, parses it, and extracts information from its code.

Consider the minimal example.

I have the following module:

```lua
local mod = {}

function mod.foo(a, ...)
    print(a, ...)
end

return mod
```

And the following driver code:

```lua
local M = require "mod"
M.foo('a', 1)
M.foo('b')
```

What is the better way to retrieve the data with the "use" occurrences of the `M.foo` function?

Ideally, I would like to get the information with the name of the function being called and the values of its arguments. From the example code above, it would be enough to get the mapping like this: `{'foo': [('a', 1), ('b')]}`.

I'm not sure if Lua has functions for reflection to retrieve this information. So probably I'll need to use one of the existing parsers for Lua to get the complete AST and find the function calls I'm interested in.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: See http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#3.8 and http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can not modify the files, you can read the files into a strings then parse `mod` file and find all functions in it, then use that information to parse the target file for all uses of the mod library

```lua
functions = {}

for func in modFile:gmatch("function mod%.(%w+)") do
    functions[func] = {}
end

for func, call in targetFile:gmatch("M%.(%w+)%(([^%)]+)%)") do
    args = {}
    for arg in string.gmatch(call, "([^,]+)") do
        table.insert(args, arg)
    end

    table.insert(functions[func], args)
end
```

Resulting table can then be serialized

```lua
    ['foo'] = {{"'a'", " 1"}, {"'b'"}}
```

3 possible gotchas:

1. `M` is not a very unique name and could vary possibly match unintended function calls to another library.
2. This example does not handle if there is a function call made inside the arg list. e.g. `myfunc(getStuff(), true)`
3. The resulting table does not know the typing of the args so they are all save as strings representations.

---

If modifying the target file is an option you can create a wrapper around your `required` module

```lua
function log(mod)
    local calls = {}
    local wrapper = {
        __index = function(_, k)
            if mod[k] then
                return function(...)
                    calls[k] = calls[k] or {}
                    table.insert(calls[k], {...})

                    return mod[k](...)
                end
            end
        end,
    }

    return setmetatable({},wrapper), calls
end
```

then you use this function like so.

```lua
local M, calls = log(require("mod"))
M.foo('a', 1)
M.foo('b')
```

If your module is not just `function`s you would need to handle that in the wrapper, this wrapper assumes all indexes are a function.

after all your calls you can serialize the `calls` table to get the history of all the calls made. For the example code the table looks like

```lua
{
    ['foo'] = {{'a', 1}, {'b'}}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a very nice solution. But, ideally, I would like to get the same data without modifying the script. I understand that this is not possible using the wrapper around `require`, so I'll leave the question open for now, maybe someone will have other ideas.

Comment: I have added a solution which works by reading the target files.

Comment: Hmm, using regexp is another option to avoid using a complete Lua parser. Thank you, I got the idea. I thought maybe there are some special libraries or reflection tools in the language that would simplify this task, but, apparently, I will have to parse the code.